# Unknown column 'main_table.custom_design_apply' in field list

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, select

I recently started monitoring the logs on my magento installation (version 1.9.1). I noticed an error recurring and strangely it originates from a core Mage class - specifically `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat` class on line 1391.

The code builds a `Select` object where it adds a field `main_table.custom_design_apply` from a table which resolves to `catalog_category_flat_store_1`. Now here is the problem, I tried inspecting that table and discovered that field really does not exist. The code below shows more for the construct.

```
$select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
        ->from(
            array('main_table' => $this->getMainStoreTable($category->getStoreId())),
            array(
                'main_table.entity_id',
                'main_table.custom_design',
                'main_table.custom_design_apply', //<-- the strange field
                'main_table.custom_design_from',
                'main_table.custom_design_to',
            )
        )
        ->where('main_table.entity_id IN (?)', $pathIds)
        ->where('main_table.is_active = ?', '1')
        ->order('main_table.path ' . Varien_Db_Select::SQL_DESC);
    $result = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchAll($select);//here is line 1391
```

I am stuck between overriding the class and removing the field or add the column manually in the table. Nonetheless, why would this be. Is it a bug on Mage's side or I am not getting the whole picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's dead code. I tried to search in magento for this attribute and found that at one moment exists such attribute and in one version this attribute was removed.

https://magecracker.wordpress.com/tag/main_table-custom_design_apply/

I think you may completely remove this row.